# How to iterate on a Flux to produce a new Flux and still work in a Reactive way?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have 2 methods, respectively producing a `Flux<String>` and a `Flux<Integer>`.

```
public Flux<String> buildName() {
        return Flux.just(personProcessor.buildName());
    }

public Flux<Integer> computeAge() {
        return Flux.just(personProcessor.computeAge());
    }
```

These methods generate randomized values to populate a Person object.

Now I would like to iterate and create X Person with randomized values in each of them.

I have created a new Flux (`processor` is the name of the service holding the methods) :

```
Flux<Person> persons = Flux.zip(processor.buildName(), processor.computeAge(),
                (name, age) -> Person.builder().name(name).age(age).build() );
```

My problem is that when I iterate with a regular loop on the "persons" Flux, I always get Person objects with the same values for name and age. I think it's normal because my loop only subscribes to the Flux and then get the same "first" object of the Flux.
I just don't know how to iterate on the Flux "persons" so that I will obtain each time a Person object with its own name and age values.

How can I iterate X times over this Flux in order to get X Person objects with randomized values ?

Of course, this iteration should also produce a Flux that will let me process the Person object.

Comment: What is the return type of `personProcessor.buildName()`?

Comment: @lkatiforis it's String

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify it as follows:

```java
Flux.range(1, n)
        .map(i -> Person.builder()
                   .name(personProcessor.buildName())
                   .age(personProcessor.computeAge())
                   .build())
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides Ikatiforis's most simple solution, you can also do the following which resembles your original solution. This can be useful if the random values are provided in some asynchronous way.

```java
public Flux<String> buildName() {
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> personProcessor.buildName()).repeat();
}

public Flux<Integer> computeAge() {
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> personProcessor.computeAge()).repeat();
}
```

And then the `zip` part is pretty much the same:

```java
Flux<Person> persons = Flux.zip(processor.buildName(), processor.computeAge(),
        (name, age) -> Person.builder().name(name).age(age).build())
    .take(X);
```